# python mysql connector for mac os 10.10.1

Tags: python, mysql, macos, osx-yosemite

I am trying to install python mysql connector on my mac os 10.10.1 operating system.

I found this official page

http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python/

but as you see, there is no release version for 10.10.1

Does that mean i should install the one for 10.9? or that means the mysql connector is not yet supports for 10.10.1 ?

Comment: There is clearly no option for 10.10.1 on the link you provided. So I guess 10.9 is the way to go